# Why Floating Point Exception (FPE) is not raised?

Tags: fortran, gfortran, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am trying to catch some FPE in a Fortran code, but it doesn't seems to work on every environment.

I wrote the following code as example:

```
program test
    implicit none

    doubleprecision, dimension(1) :: x  ! used to lure the compiler

    x(1) = 1d0

    print *, 'start'
    print *, 1d0 / (1d0 - x(1))
    print *, 'end'
end program test
```

One of my machine (1) uses CentOS 7.6.1810, gfortran 4.8.5, and has an Intel Xenon as CPU. The other one (2) uses Debian 10 Buster (actually this one is on Windows 10, but I use the debian app for the WSL), gfortran 9.2.0 and has an Intel Core i5 as CPU.

When I compile the above code using

`gfortran -o test -ffpe-trap=zero -fbacktrace -g -Og test.f90`

on machine 1 and execute the code, I get what I expect, i.e.

```
$ ./test
start

Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7F2374BEC697
#1  0x7F2374BECCDE
#2  0x7F23740E827F
#3  0x400858 in MAIN__ at test.f90:9
```

However, when I do the same thing on machine 2, I get only:

```
$ ./test
start
```

Why ? And what should I do to get the SIGFPE (and other signals) error message on machine 2 ?

Comment: Welcome, I suggest to take the [tour]. Please use tag [tag:fortran] for all Fortran questions. I do get it trapped with GCC 9.21 OpenSUSE 15.0. Maybe WSL to blame?

Comment: Related? https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/3657

Comment: It seems that you need to ask Microsoft how it deals with floating exceptions under WSL.  I suspect that you'll need to get acquainted with the IEEE_ARITHMETIC intrinsic module.

Comment: Although you don't see an error message, it looks like there is still an abort.  It's the message you care about?

Comment: @VladimirF and evets Thanks. It seems indeed related with WSL. Apparently this is an old issue that might be solved with WSL 2 https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/1262#issuecomment-546831730. I don't really want to join the Windows Insider Program so I cannot test yet if this actually solves my problem.

Comment: @francescalus Yes, I care about the message. I have this kind of issue with a very complex code, and having the program just stop without indications about where the error occur makes it significantly harder to debug.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installing [WSL 2](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/install-win10) solved the problem.

```
$ ./test
start

Program received signal SIGFPE: Floating-point exception - erroneous arithmetic operation.

Backtrace for this error:
#0  0x7feab2aee8b0 in ???
#1  0x7feab2aedae3 in ???
#2  0x7feab276883f in ???
        at /build/glibc-vjB4T1/glibc-2.28/signal/../sysdeps/unix/sysv/linux/x86_64/sigaction.c:0
#3  0x4011fb in test
        at /home/user/test/test.f90:9
#4  0x401299 in main
        at /home/user/test/test.f90:11
Floating point exception
```